# setInterval() fires only once

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to update a variable every 500ms when an image upload starts and sets its value as 100 when the uploading completes. Here's the code:

```
var progress = 0
var $new = document.querySelector('#new');
var $imgupload = document.querySelector('#img-upload');
var $progress = document.querySelector('#progress');
var $percent = document.querySelector('#percent');
var interval = null;

function incrementProgress() {
    interval = window.setInterval(function() {
        $percent.innerHTML = progress+'%'
        $progress.setAttribute('value', progress)
        progress += 2;
        console.log('fired') // fires only once
    }, 500)
}

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var $img = document.querySelector('#new');
            $img.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
            $img.style.display = 'block';
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

//triggers the setInterval() and initiates image uploading

$imgupload.addEventListener('change', function() {
    incrementProgress();
    readURL(this);
});


//clears the setInterval() on image upload and sets the progress value as 100.

$new.addEventListener('load', function() {
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    $percent.innerHTML = 100+'%'
    $progress.setAttribute('value', 100)
})
```

**The Problem:**

As soon as the image uploading starts, the value of `$progress` gets set to `0` and jumps directly to `100` once the image gets uploaded. What's expected is that the `$progess` variable increments by `2` every 500ms which is not happening.

**Edit:**

Here's the working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7tmcu5g6/1/

Comment: use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

Comment: @gurvinder372 It's ```setInterval``` only. I have corrected my question.

Comment: I guess you are missing a semicolon, please check your browser's console for errors.

Comment: @gurvinder372 There are no syntactic errors in this code and the OP’s already using the console.

Comment: @gurvinder372 The code is syntactically correct.

Comment: @m-ketan But did you checked if there are any errors shown in browser's console?

Comment: @gurvinder372 Yes I did. There are no errors.

Comment: The incrementation itself works well in a JSFiddle, just tried it out. How long is the image upload taking?

Comment: @Tazavoo For testing purposes I'm uploading a ~19mb .jpeg image. It starts with 0, doesn't increment and jumps to 100 upon getting uploaded.

Comment: @m-ketan In that case please share a working snippet that demonstrate your issue.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Updated my question with a fiddle.

Comment: @m-ketan I get `VM36:106 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

Comment: @gurvinder372 Try now. Fixed the issue.

Comment: I guess the browser is freezing for the duration of upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps true progression would be better? Simply replace `setInterval` with `reader.onprogress`:

```js
var $new = document.querySelector('#new');
var $imgupload = document.querySelector('#img-upload');
var $progress = document.querySelector('#progress');
var $percent = document.querySelector('#percent');

function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onprogress = function (e) {
            var progress = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
            $percent.innerHTML = progress + "%";
            $progress.setAttribute('value', progress);
        }

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var $img = document.querySelector('#new');
            $img.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
            $img.style.display = 'block';
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$imgupload.addEventListener('change', function () {     
    readURL(this);
});

$new.addEventListener('load', function () {
    $percent.innerHTML = 100 + '%'
    $progress.setAttribute('value', 100)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<progress max="100" value="0" id="progress"></progress>
<span id="percent">0%</span>
<label for="img-upload">Upload</label>
<input type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" id="img-upload">
<img src='#' id='new' width="200" height="200" style="display: none">
```

Comment: Looks promising! I'll try this asap.